# How to retain the value of a global variable after initialising it in constructor in python?

Tags: python, django, oop

I have faced this issue while creating a form using Django.

```
class DetailForm(forms.Form):
    row_id = 2

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global row_id
        row_id = kwargs.pop('r_id')
        super(DetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    row=Prewash.objects.get(id=row_id)
    id = forms.CharField(label='ID',initial=row_id, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
```

Here within the **init**()  the global variable row_id is being updated. But it does not get reflected in the last line when I try to retrieve the value from the db.

I need a way to retain the value of the variable I am trying to set within the constructor(without using instance or methods).

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do here? why not just assign value `self.row_id` instead of declaring global variables?

Comment: I have edited the question to serve your answer. I cant create the self instance because outside the constructor or function I can't use the self instance. Here I am trying to create a dynamic form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change field attributes based on then form's context, you can do that by accessing and updating that specific field in the `__init__` function.

Something like this should work:

```
class DetailForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.CharField(label='ID', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        row_id = kwargs.pop('r_id', 2)
        super(DetailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['id'].initial = row_id
```

Comment: Yeah! thanks. I think that might work. Will try and let you know @v1k45

Answer (score 0):

In a python class we use object attributes or static attributes.
if you want access object attributes you have to use

```
self.<attribtute_name>
```

and if you want access static attributes we use

```
<<ClassName>>.<<attribute_name>>
```

See this link [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: Well I changed the code accordingly.

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): DetailForm.row_id = kwargs.pop('r_id')

row=Prewash.objects.get(id=DetailForm.row_id)

But now I get an error: row=Prewash.objects.get(id=DetailForm.row_id)
NameError: name 'DetailForm' is not defined